# How to use entries in a listA to refer other lists with names that have prefixes same as ListA's entries

Tags: scripting, tcl

#Suppose i have a list name

```
set modules [list]
lappend modules moduleA
lappend modules moduleB
lappend modules moduleC
```

#and i have other list naming

```
set moduleA_sig [list]
lappend moduleA......
set moduleB_sig [list]
lappend moduleB_sig ....
set moduleC_sig [list]
lappend moduleC_sig ....
```

#How can I use my "modules" list entries to access though the other list, eg:

```
foreach mod $modules 
{
    llength ${mod}_sig
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `upvar` is to use `set <var_name>` to retrieve the value of var_name.  When <var_name> is `${mod}_sig`, then you can use `set` to retrieve the value of the variable without the possibility of altering the value of the original variable (like `upvar`)

```
set modules {moduleA moduleB moduleC}

set moduleA_sig {1 2 3 4}
set moduleB_sig {11 22 33 44}
set moduleC_sig {111 222 333 444}

foreach mod $modules {
    # Get the value of the variable named ${mod}_sig.
    puts "$mod: [set ${mod}_sig]"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use an array (Or [dict](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.html)) to hold values instead of trying to compose variable names on the fly at runtime.

Array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set modules {moduleA moduleB moduleC}

set sig(moduleA) {1 2 3 4}
set sig(moduleB) {11 22 33 44}
set sig(moduleC) {111 222 333 444}

foreach mod $modules {
    puts "$mod: $sig($mod)"
}
```

Or with a dict:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set modules {moduleA moduleB moduleC}

dict set sig moduleA {1 2 3 4}
dict set sig moduleB {11 22 33 44}
dict set sig moduleC {111 222 333 444}

foreach mod $modules {
    puts "$mod: [dict get $sig $mod]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you want the [`upvar`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm) command
to "alias" one variable to another.

```
set modules {moduleA moduleB moduleC}

set moduleA_sig {1 2 3 4}
set moduleB_sig {11 22 33 44}
set moduleC_sig {111 222 333 444}

foreach mod $modules {
    upvar 0 ${mod}_sig this
    puts [list $mod $this]
}
```

outputs

```
moduleA {1 2 3 4}
moduleB {11 22 33 44}
moduleC {111 222 333 444}
```

Here, use level 0 to indicate the current stack frame.

Any modifications you make to `$this` will be reflected in `$moduleX_sig`.

```
set x 42
upvar 0 x y
incr y
puts $x      ;# => 43
```